# 'Modernizing' a Python 2.7 ZIP Cracker to Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, argparse, optparse

I've been trying to 'modernize' the ZIP Cracker code from "Violent Python" by TJ O'Connor which was written in Python 2.7 (I presume)

The original code follows:

```
import zipfile
import optparse
from threading import Thread


def extractFile(zFile, password):
    try:
        zFile.extractall(pwd=password)
        print
        '[+] Found password ' + password + '\n'
    except:
        pass


def main():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser("usage%prog " + \
                                   "-f <zipfile> -d <dictionary>")
    parser.add_option('-f', dest='zname', type='string', \
                      help='specify zip file')
    parser.add_option('-d', dest='dname', type='string', \
                      help='specify dictionary file')
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    if (options.zname == None) | (options.dname == None):
        print(parser.usage)
        exit(0)
    else:
        zname = options.zname
        dname = options.dname
    zFile = zipfile.ZipFile(zname)
    passFile = open(dname)
    for line in passFile.readlines():
        password = line.strip('\n')
        t = Thread(target=extractFile, args=(zFile, password))
        t.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My attempt of modernizing was using `argparse` instead of `optparse`. I did manage to recreate the args but couldn't get the code to work properly. What I mean is to get accept an input like `Project.py -z "Generic ZIP Name.zip" -d "Dictionary.txt"`

My 'modernized' code as follows:

```
import zipfile
import argparse
from threading import Thread

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Unzips selected .zip using a dictionary attack")

# Creates -z arg
parser.add_argument("-z", "--zip", metavar="", required=True, help="Location and the name of the .zip file.")

# Creates -d arg
parser.add_argument("-d", "--dictionary", metavar="", required=True, help="Location and the name of the dictionary.")
args = parser.parse_args()


def extract_zip(zipFile, password):
    try:
        zipFile.extractall(pwd=password.encode())
        print(f"[+] Password for the .zip: {password} \n")
    except Exception:
        pass


def main(zip, dictionary):
    if (zip == None) | (dictionary == None):
        print(parser.usage)
        exit(0)
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zip)
    pass_file = open(dictionary)
    for line in pass_file.readlines():
        password = line.strip('\n')
        t = Thread(target=extract_zip, args=(zip_file, password))
        t.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # USAGE - Project.py -z zipname.zip -d dictionary.txt
    main(args.zip, args.dictionary)
```

An error that I've been getting is this:

```
(venv) C:\Users\USER\Documents\Jetbrains\PyCharm\Project>Project.py -z "Generic ZIP Name.zip" -d "Most Common 10k Passwords.txt"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Jetbrains\PyCharm\Project\Project.py", line 37, in <module>
    main(args.zip, args.dictionary)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Jetbrains\PyCharm\Project\Project.py", line 29, in main
    for line in pass_file.readlines():
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 193: character maps to <undefined>
```

Not sure how can I fix this as I have no proper idea how to 'modernize' that piece of code. I've been trying but getting no proper results and would like some assistance if possible.

I also have a side question. While looking for answers I've stumbled upon some similar posts, where replies stated that instead of using `Thread`/`threading` one should use `multithread` because of `GIL` (Not quite sure what that is). Does this still hold? Should I replace `threading` to `multithreading`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your current problem is the Python 3 bytes/strings distinction that doesn't exist in Python 2. I reckon you should tackle that first. You don't need to substitute `argparse` for `optparse`. `argparse` still exists, and because the APIs are very similar but not identical you risk introducing subtle, hard-to-find bugs. Changing the threading mechanism will probably entail a rewrite of code that is difficult to understand.

Comment: @BoarGules From what I read on the forums that `optparse` has been discontinued and not supported on 3.7 and `argparse` is the continuation of `optparse`

Comment: Perhaps, but it is not your immediate problem. Once you have crucial issues like encoding fixed, it is time to worry about replacing deprecated libraries that still actually work. Whatever the forums say, `optparse` is still part of the standard library in 3.7. Get the code working before you start prettying it up.

Comment: @BoarGules I’d say the code is “pretty” already. Issue is `optparse` only works till 2.7, not on 3.7. And with 2.7 being discontinued I am trying to get the code working on 3.7, which is the issue; as I have to use `argparse` but I can’t get it to work.

Comment: But `optparse` *does* work on 3.7. Read this if you don't believe me: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/optparse.html

Comment: @BoarGules so what I have to do is `from optparse import OptionParser` instead of `import optparse` to make it work on 3.x+/3.7?

Comment: I just installed Python 3.7.2 to be sure of having the very latest version. I typed `import optparse` at the `>>>` prompt. It worked. I suggest you go through the same  exercise. The `from ... import` in the documentation is an *example*. The 2.7 docs have exactly the same example.

Comment: @BoarGules importing works, but using the module is problematic. Thats what I am trying to say.

Comment: Then post a question outlining the behaviour you are expecting from `optparse` and the behaviour you are getting. I suspect the problem is likelier to be the way it is being called than something that no longer works inside it.

Comment: @BoarGules Just in case though, any proper way to switch from `optparse` to `argparse` while not having to rewrite all the program? Like is there a guide on switching/upgrading from `optparse` to `argparse`?

Comment: It's probably not too hard but to do that you need a working program with the barest minimum of changes needed to get it running under Python 3.

Comment: The eror isn't in `argparse`.  It's in reading one of the files.  Just to be sure, do a `print(args)` to see what the parser produced.`

Comment: @BoarGules Using `from optparse import OptionParser` in my code instead of `import optparse` (Using the book's original code) yields this: https://gist.github.com/Arszilla/ea4b7f316bea0fc553984ff1097fb5d4

I attached the revised code in the gist.. Not quite sure how to fix that.

Comment: And that has nothing whatsoever to do with `optparse`. As I said at the very beginning, *your current problem is the Python 3 bytes/strings distinction that doesn't exist in Python 2*. The code you are working with is reading what Python 3 would regard as bytes, but is attempting to convert them as if they were strings encoded as Windows 1252. Get hold of a book on how to do Python 3 conversions, for example Lennart Regebro's *Porting to Python 3* (Colliberty 2013, ISBN 978-1-490-36333-9) and find out what you have to do to deal with the unicode/bytes distinction in Python 3.

Comment: @BoarGules You were right, apologies for being a hard head. I used `io` instead to open the text document as it has symbols like #, . etc (Which I noticed on a closer examination. Used `pass_file = io.open(dictionary, mode="r", encoding="utf-8")` instead.

Comment: It's always tempting to believe that a drop-in replacement will magically make a problem go away. The bytes/strings issue is the hardest part of a conversion because it is not fully amenable to automated tools. It requires an understanding of the intent of the original code. And if that intent relies on the Python 2 bytes/strings ambiguity it is harder still.

Answer (score 0):

1. Each file in a zip can have its own password.
2. Multiprocessing.
3. Open the file in each worker.
4. Why have options when you have two mandatory arguments?

Comment: This is a ZIP cracker that uses a bruteforce attack. -z specifies the zip’s location with .zip at the end (i.e -z zipname.zip if its in the same location as .py). Same concept goes for -d as its the dictionary/password .txt file. As for multiprocessing, how could I do that, as I believe you are saying muliprocessing is better than threading to do a bruteforce attack.

Comment: Yes, it is CPU bound. Multiprocessing gives you processes with their own heaps connected together via pipes and shared memory.

Comment: So Multiprocessing uses GPU instead or what?